# How to make a fluid "timeline" in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a fluid "timeline"-like row in Bootstrap. See an example of what I'm looking for [here](http://www.theladbible.com/) (basically a row of boxes that stack up independently of the height).

I have tried to use this great template: http://codepen.io/emaildano/pen/LEbLeQ
Code:

```
<section class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid">
    <a href="#"><div class="item i1"><span class="date">2015</span><p class="title">Content</p></div></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

But it does not work for me on my site. They stack up on just one row, instead of two. Just like this:
[image: Example]

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I also made  PSD for it, and thought it could look like this:
[image: PSD]

However, the problem is that I do not know how to make this in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Just set **`width`** to **`100%`** instead of 1000px

```
.grid-container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdqWBX

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. The boxes just aligned to the left when I did that.

Comment: You want a full width or in a container ? You said fluid which means 100% width

Comment: If you use bootstrap, add a div container around your code

Comment: I tried that earlier, it didn't change much, just moved it some pixels and positioned the circle out of the box. See [this](http://puu.sh/hYww2/7d2042638d.png)